# May I use a variable as routeName in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

My partner and I are new to react-native. We try to apply react-native to build a small application, and we have a homepage with FlatList and navigate between different screens by react-navigation.

We want each row in FletList can navigate to different screens. So, I want to put a variable as routeName and it can get the routename from the DATA for FlatList. However, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

The question is: can I use a variable as routeName? If so, how I can make it happen. If not, is there any other way to achieve the goal?

--

Here is the data for FlatList and we add "nextpage" and hope it can direct the navigator as a routename.

```
const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'a1',
      title: 'Task1',
      type: 'c1',
      requester: 'lab',
      createtime:'2019-12-23',
      nextpage: 'instructionScreen',
    },
    {
        id: 'a2',
        title: 'Task2',
        type: 'c1',
        requester: 'lab',
        createtime:'2019-11-16',
        nextpage: 'introSliders',
    },
  ];
```

The navigator works when we put 'introSliders' after this.props.navigation.navigate; however, it doesn't work if I put {item.nextpage}.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'List',
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>List</Text>
        <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={
                ({ item }) => {
                    return (
                      <Item title={item.title} 
                        type={item.type} 
                        requester={item.requester} 
                        createtime={item.createtime}
                        action={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('introSliders')}
                        // action={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({item.nextpage})}             
                      />
                    )
                }
            }
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate({item.nextpage})` is a syntax error. did you try `this.props.navigation.navigate(item.nextpage)` ?

Comment: It works. omg. Thank you for pointing out this!